# vbscript permission denied: getobject

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wmi-service

I'm trying to execute a batch file which is located in a server from a vbscript in my local system.

Below code throws permission denied while accessing GETOBJECT

```
strDomain = "SBICAD"
strComputer = "10.29.83.22"
Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objSWbemServices = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, _
"root\cimv2", _
 "ec12345", _
"sorry@1", _
 "MS_409", _
 "ntlmdomain:" + strDomain)

        objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!" & _
                        "\\" & strComputer & _
                        "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")



result = objWMIService.Create("C:\script\checkremote.bat", Null, Null,process)


Msgbox result 
WScript.Quit
```

Is there anyway to pass my server login credentials on GetObject?

**Note: The user ec12345 has admin rights.**

Answer (score 2):

You don't need use the `GetObject` method because you are already connected with the `ConnectServer` function. So you only must use the `ExecQuery` method which will be executed using the same connection.

```
Set objWMIService = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")
```

Comment: But I couldn't create process using objSWbemServices. My target is to make this "objWMIService.Create("C:\script\checkremote.bat", Null, Null,process)" work.

Comment: Error permission denied : GetObject

Comment: @user3186990 You were already told to not use `GetObject`. What error do you get when you instantiate `objWMIService` the way @RRUZ suggested? Note that `ExecQuery` returns a collection, so it'd be better to use `Set objWMIService = objSWbemServices.Get("Win32_Process")`.

Comment: Im new to vbscript.. Actually im looking run a script that is located in remote server. I tried with code posted and got permission denied error. Please suggest how can i do that.

Comment: @user3186990 Please update your question with your modified code and the exact error message.

Comment: Im trying with posted code to execute a batch script located in remote server. It throws permission denied: getobject. Please suggest or modify my script to successfully execute the batch file on remote server.

Comment: @user3186990 For the third time: **DO NOT USE `GetObject`.** It doesn't work the way you seem to think. Please follow the advice you're given.